# Add text to a html form

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to add text on it's own to describe some steps without any input box in a form. Is it possible to do this? Line that should just be text is:

```
<p>For a new location please add an entry</p>
```

I tried it without the `<p>` tags but again no success. Apologies if this seems very simplistic but I saw nothing on this on w3schools, this site or just a google search.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name <input name="name" type="text">
<br>
Email address of user <input name="email" type="text">
<br>
Phone Number <input name="phone" type="text">
<br>
Town <input name="town" type="text">
<br>
County <select name="county">
<option>    Outside Ireland </option>
<option>    Antrim  </option>
<option>    Armagh  </option>
<br>
<p>For a new location please add an entry</p>
<br>
Name of New Location <input name="newlocation" type="text">
<br>
Name of Location <input name="location" type="text">
<br>
Link in Google Maps <input name="gmapslink" type="text">
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: My apologies I'm a fool. Editing the code I removed the closing </select> statement. This can be closed. Apologies for wasting peoples time.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like, having a preset text input in the box? i believe that would be value="desired value:

ex.

`input name="town" value="Text Desired" type="text"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `placeholder` attribute to accomplish this

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="ds_email"
  placeholder="Please, enter your e-mail here"
/>
```